# pycharm python console single instance

Tags: python, pycharm, single-instance

I'm using PyCharm community edition 3.3

How can I disable multiple instances for each file running in python console?

In previous editions there as a checkbox in the Run -> Edit Configuration window, but it was removed..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean 2018.3.3? Enable **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Use existing console for "Run with Python console"**.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Is there also a possibility to run a different console to each script running (but still only a single instance for each script)?